# Objective-C: Mutating parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it safe to have a method edit a parameter and not be inside a category.

For example, just having a method like this in a ViewController subclass:

```
-(void)editArray:(NSMutableArray*)array
{
    [array removeLastObject];
}
```

And calling `[self editArray:(someArray)];` inside the view controller where someArray is a strong atomic property. It seems to work when I test it, I just don't know if this is discouraged. I know I could easily do this in a category, I just want to know if something like this is safe.

Comment: It's not less safe because of being a parameter than it would be in some other section of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is safe, as long you're not modifying the reference, just the contents of the parameter object. E.g. assigning to `array` inside the method would not work, you'd need to pass it by reference instead. As regards style, consider how the errors are returned from many Cocoa Touch framework methods:

```
NSError *error = nil;
[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
```

Here, too, the parameter object, in this case `&error`, is modified inside the method. So I think you're good from the style perspective as well :)

Comment: this is a different situation than removeFileAtPath:error: The error parameter is a handle(pointer to an object (id*)), so the object passed back may be different than the object passed in. In the question the object itself is being modified, not replaced.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not the exact same thing. My point is that the Apple code does modify parameters inside methods, in this case by assigning a new value to `*error`. So it's not something that should be avoided because of the "good style" concerns.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the array while it is being mutated Cocoa will throw an exception `*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x7f96432004c0> was mutated while being enumerated.`

Consider the code:

```
NSMutableArray* a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[@"a", @"b", @"c"]];
for (id x in a) {
    [a removeLastObject];
}
```

In this case it would be unsafe and cause your application to crash. Abstracting the removeLastObject message into another message doesn't really change anything.

It will also not be safe if done on a background thread.